# NPM erno 4048 operation not permitted after trying everything

Tags: npm, npm-install

I used to be able to npm install packages no problem. But something changed where npm install doesn't work for anything on my C: drive.

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install package
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

With ADMIN in command prompt, powershell, and in VS Code, ive tried:

- Confirming folders are not read-only
- giving full control to user and admin
- npm cache clean --force
- npm set prefix 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm'
- restarting multiple times
- running npm config edit, and changing prefix variable to 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm'
- No ransomware protection and turned off windows firewall
- npm install -g npm@latest --force

I'm running some react projects, and I recently installed and uninstalled Docker. I still get the above error when running 'npm install'. I'm completely out of ideas and things to try.